# Hidden fields are missing while doing 'view source'

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have two hidden fields in my jsp form. When i get the page in browser and do 'view source', I could see only the first hidden field, not the second field.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<%=url%>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value="<%=age%>" />
```

Is the syntax wrong? Please help

**Update:**

Code:

```
<form name="displayForm" action="javascript: submitPage();"> 

<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<%=url%>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value="<%=age%>" /> 
<span class="notice required">* indicates required field</span> Source in the browser is 
<form name="displayForm" action="javascript: submitPage();"> 
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="unix.com"; /> 
<span class="notice required">* indicates required field</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Yes, still i cant see the second field. See the source in the browser below

<form name="displayForm" action="javascript: submitPage();">
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="http://www.unix.com" />
<span class="notice required">* indicates required field</span>

Comment: Are you sure the JSP has recompiled since you put the second hidden field into the JSP?

Comment: Code is 
<form name="displayForm" action="javascript: submitPage();">
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<%=url%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value="<%=age%>" />

<span class="notice required">* indicates required field</span>

Source in the browser is 
<form name="displayForm" action="javascript: submitPage();"> <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="unix.com"; /> <span class="notice required">* indicates required field</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the tomcat serving the JSP has actually deployed your changes. Try to locate the file "jspfilename_jsp.java" and look if your hidden field statements are actually in there. You might want to take a look at Lambda Probe for Tomcat, which cleans the cache with a click of a mouse, forcing a rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

No. It must be there. You might be conditionally rendering it.

Comment: Code is <form name="displayForm" action="javascript: submitPage();"> <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<%=url%>" /> <input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value="<%=age%>" /> <span class="notice required">* indicates required field</span> Source in the browser is <form name="displayForm" action="javascript: submitPage();"> <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="unix.com"; /> <span class="notice required">* indicates required field</span>

Answer (score 0):

which browser do you use? Did you try to inspect it with some sort of "developer tool" (Chrome - Developer tools, FF - Firebug, IE8+ - Developer tools)?

When you submit the form what happens, what do you get for "age"?